# The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp, remote-server, windows-firewall

In my remote server I log in SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio. It works.

But on my PC when I try to log in I get an error. I add port to server name but I still get the same error. My TCP/IP is enabled. Port is enabled

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

[image]

Comment: Is the SQL Browser running on the server?  For more see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: @ReleaseObject sql browser services is running.Here is screen: http://i.hizliresim.com/lrbAJr.png

Comment: Here's a handy troubleshooting guide from Microsoft.  
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx